# Shell calling perl and returning back string to Shell Script

Tags: perl, shell

I have a shell script , i want to call a perl script to do some compute, once perl is called i want perl to process it and while returning i want it to return not exit code but a string back to shell script ? how can i do that?

Here is my simple piece of code calling perl in shell script
VAR=$(perl Test.pl)

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty would be to have the perl script `print` the Information to STDOUT and just call it in your Shell script by backticks or just as you did.
Along the lines of

```
VAR=`perl Test.pl`
```

This will put everything the perl script printed to STDOUT into VAR.

Comment: Hmm, how do i use backticks in code examples? Backslash seems to not work. edit: nvm, found it out. I tried to have it in a inline codeexample and did not manage to escape the backticks. ^^

Comment: There is no need to substitute backticks for `$(...)` (in fact, the latter is generally preferred). That distracts from the *real* answer (having Perl print its output to `stdout`).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Agreed, though i allways use backticks and didn't even think about wether or not to put them. Clarified my answer a Little. And to Nik: Generally yes, this method acts as if you would run your perl script, copy all the Output it wrote to the console and then pasted that stuff right behind VAR=